# nested lambda in scheme

Tags: function, lambda, scheme, chicken-scheme

I'm trying to define a function in scheme that prints a message when called, followed by a newline. To do this I've attempted to use nested lambda like this:

```
(define message 
    (lambda (msg)
        (lambda (newL) 
            (newline)
        )
    (display msg))  
)
```

However, when I do this, and call the function like:

```
(message "#f")
```

it only prints the #f, and does not create a newline. If I reverse the lambda orders in the function and swap the position of the newL and msg lambda's, then it only prints a newline and doesn't display the message!

The function is called in this block of code:

```
(define (permute upList)
    (if (null? upList)
        (message "#f")
         ;permutation code
    )
)
```

The error message received when not using nested lambda's is as follows:

Error: call of non-procedure: #

```
    Call history:

    <syntax>          (permute (quote ()))
    <syntax>          (quote ())
    <syntax>          (##core#quote ())
    <eval>    (permute (quote ()))
    <eval>    [permute] (null? upList)
    <eval>    [permute] (message "#f")
    <eval>    [message] ((display msg) (newline))
    <eval>    [message] (display msg)
    <eval>    [message] (newline)   <--
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need a nested lambda at all? Just do `(define message (lambda (msg) (display msg) (newline)))`, or, even simpler, `(define (message msg) (display msg) (newline))`.

Comment: Why would you use nested lambdas?

Comment: It gives me an error saying "call of non-procedure" because I'm calling it in a function that take's in a list as an argument.

Comment: I’m not sure that your question is answerable as-is... given the code you’ve posted, I don’t see any place that “call of non-procedure” error would be coming from. Can you post a little more context along with the full error message?

Comment: @AlexisKing this is the error message:

Error: call of non-procedure: #<unspecified>

        Call history:

        <syntax>          (permute (quote ()))
        <syntax>          (quote ())
        <syntax>          (##core#quote ())
        <eval>    (permute (quote ()))
        <eval>    [permute] (null? upList)
        <eval>    [permute] (message "#f")
        <eval>    [message] ((display msg) (newline))
        <eval>    [message] (display msg)
        <eval>    [message] (newline)   <--

Comment: @Starscreen60 Can you please put that information in your question instead of in a comment so it can be more clearly formatted? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code, you only create a procedure object, which is then immediately discarded:

```scm
(define message 
  (lambda (msg)
    (lambda (newL) 
      (newline))
    (display msg)))
```

It's like doing:

```
(define message 
  (lambda (msg)
    1234
    (display msg)))
```

The 1234 here **is** evaluated, but the value is completely ignored.

If you have a procedure and you want to call it immediately, you have to wrap in an extra set of parentheses (because in Scheme, in general, parens represent application):

```
(define message 
  (lambda (msg)
    ((lambda (newL) 
       (newline)) #f)
    (display msg)))
```

But, as others have pointed out, there's no need to create a nested lambda in this case.  Plus, the procedure ignores its argument anyway, which is why I had to invent an argument to pass; I used #f because that's the typical "don't care" value.  You can just do:

```
(define message 
  (lambda (msg)
    (newline)
    (display msg)))
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that clarifies my doubt

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it so this question is marked as "answered". The main reason I'm on Stack Overflow is to avoid CHICKEN questions remaining unanswered!